# virt-install / virsh create tries to launch VM after install

Tags: arch-linux, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I am trying to create a script to simplify the process, by which I can create a paravirtualized vm. When my script reaches the part, where it creates the vm, it freezes, because it apparently tries to remove the GPU(according to dmesg `NVRM: Attempting to remove device 0000:0a:00.0 with non-zero usage count!` ). I've tried to fix this, by using `virt-install --print-xml=1`, parsing the output of that to a file which I then reference in `virsh create`, but the same issue occurs. I've also tried `virt-install --noautoconsole --no-install=yes`, but that had no effect as well. `virt-install -p` caused an error saying that I need to use xen, but I use kvm and from my understanding(correct me on this if I'm wrong kvm is used for paravirtualisation, while xen is used for full virtualization). The error seems to cause libvirtd to freeze, as it's not possible to kill the command / restart libvirtd and then use commands like `sudo virsh list --all`(which will cause a freeze). The issue is only solved, by restarting the PC

Answer (score 0):

I will not mark this as fixing the issue, but there is a workaround to the issue:

```bash
virt-install --print-xml $commands >"/etc/libvirt/qemu/$vm_name\.xml"
xmlstartlet ...
virsh define "/etc/libvirt/qemu/$vm_name\.xml"
```

by using virsh define instead, it won't start the vm

also if you edit the xml file afterwards rerun `virsh define $xml_file`

**I do not think however that this adequately answers the question, as it's a workaround and there has to be a flag that disables running the vm on install**